# How to check how many characters in variable, and add space between characters in that var?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 'price' variable that contains some integer number from a MySQL database.

I want to check how many numbers the 'price' variable contains, and add a space in the variable depending on how many numbers. See below:

Example:

If 'price' is 150000 I would like the output to be 150 000 (notice the space).
OR, if it is 19000 I would like it to output 19 000...

How would you do this the easiest way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format):

```
$str = number_format($number, 0, '.', ' ');
```

Comment: Will this work on INT? I cant get it to work, it does display the price, but not the space ex 190000 is the same after formatting it

Comment: It doesn't matter if the data is INT in the database; PHP initially sees all data from db queries as strings, then converts implicitly as needed. Greg's code should work. How are you presenting the number_format() return to the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`number_format` function](http://php.net/number_format) to format a number:

```
number_format($number, 0, '.', ' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you are trying to do is format the number with grouped thousands and a space as the thousand separator, use this.

number_format($number, 2, '.', ' ');

Comment: Will this work on INT? I cant get it to work, it does display the price, but not the space
ex 190000 is the same after formatting it...

Comment: This will work with both int and float. I applied the above function 190000 just a while ago, and correctly displayed '190 000.00'. It's very likely you are doing it wrong. If you care to post the entire block of code, it'll be easier to catch the bug. On another note, remember that you can adjust the second parameter of the above function to specify desired number of digits after the decimal point. So if the number in question is strictly an integer, you might just want to make the second parameter '0' instead of current '2'.